# How to get the position of the first occurrence of a digit in a postgres select

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, parsing

I have a field that has the SDK name and version and it is not standardized so that I can easily extract just the name and the version. These are contrived values but represent the possible values I am working with:

- JavaScript/2.3.4
- JavaScript/4.3.1
- Android4.6.5
- Android3.2.1
- Swift4.5.3
- Swift/3.1.1.5

As you can see, the use of "/" is not consistent and I need a way to parse the alpha from the numeric consistently so that I end up with two columns like this:

```
JavaScript     2.3.4
JavaScript     4.3.1
Android        4.6.5
Android        3.2.1
Swift          4.5.3
Swift          3.1.1.5
```

I have searched for different ways to do this but nothing I have found seems to do what I required.

Ultimately, I need to put this into a Postgres SELECT statement like this:

#### EDIT

I think the DISTINCT keyword is unneeded and confusing. It was originally part of a COUNT/GROUP BY query, but for simplicity sake, I just want to list all rows with the three columns: sdk, sdk_name and sdk_version separately. From there I will use the best parsing formula from the answers to do as I require.

```
SELECT sdk, [parse sdk name formula] as "sdk_name", [parse sdk version formula] as "sdk_version"
```

Furthermore, I don't have a fixed list of SDKs to provide in the query so I am not sure the `with/as/values` strategy works for me but something I was not aware of and looks useful. I suppose the with/values can just be another SELECT query, though.

Comment: To all that answered my question, big thanks for the quick turnaround. I will try all strategies and post back results and select the best answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the regex function [`substring()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
with my_data(sdk) as (
values
    ('JavaScript/2.3.4'),
    ('JavaScript/4.3.1'),
    ('Android4.6.5'),
    ('Android3.2.1'),
    ('Swift4.5.3'),
    ('Swift/3.1.1.5')
)

select 
    substring(sdk from '[^\d/]*') as sdk_name, 
    substring(sdk from '\d.*') as sdk_version
from my_data 

  sdk_name  | sdk_version 
------------+-------------
 JavaScript | 2.3.4
 JavaScript | 4.3.1
 Android    | 4.6.5
 Android    | 3.2.1
 Swift      | 4.5.3
 Swift      | 3.1.1.5
(6 rows)
```

---

Update.

You can place your `select` query in the `with` part (instead of `values`):

```
with my_data(sdk) as (
    <select sdk from ...>
)
select 
    substring(sdk from '[^\d/]*') as sdk_name, 
    substring(sdk from '\d.*') as sdk_version
from my_data
```

or in the `from` clause:

```
select 
    substring(sdk from '[^\d/]*') as sdk_name, 
    substring(sdk from '\d.*') as sdk_version
from (
    <select sdk from ...>
) my_data
```

Comment: This is interesting if the `with/as/values can be a dynamic list like another SELECT statement. We don't have an SDKs table so it would have to be a SELECT on the same table I am trying to query. Not sure this will actually do what I need to do but perhaps the `substring` formula is all I need from your answer. I will give it go. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @klin, I will try that. Before you updated your answer I got an error from my query system: Mode Analytics using AWS Athena client. I got this error on the `substring(sdk from '[^\d/]*') as sdk_name` :  
**[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:15: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(7)) for function substr. Expected: substr(varchar(x), bigint, bigint) , substr(varchar(x), bigint) , substr(char(x), bigint, bigint) , substr(char(x), bigint)** - this is probably a postgres version issue or Mode support issue, right?

Comment: I think so, though unfortunately I've never used this software.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [translate](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for this:

```
SELECT sdk, translate(sdk,'0123456789/.','') AS sdk_name, 
       translate(lower(sdk),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/','') AS sdk_version 
FROM   table1;
```

Working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/925df/9)

EDIT (by Gordon):

This is a good idea.  I find it simpler to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(sdk, '[0-9/.]', '', 'g') as sdk_name,
       regexp_replace(sdk, '[a-zA-Z/]', '', 'g') as sdk_version
```

Comment: This looks really straight forward and I will give it go along with the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression parsing is quite compute-intensive, so rather than using two function calls (as in the other answers), you should combine them into a single call and then extract the desired values from the result:

```
WITH d(sdk) AS (
  VALUES
    ('JavaScript/2.3.4'),
    ('JavaScript/4.3.1'),
    ('Android4.6.5'),
    ('Android3.2.1'),
    ('Swift4.5.3'),
    ('Swift/3.1.1.5'),
    ('C#/23.1') )
SELECT unq.sdk, re.match[1] AS sdk_name, re.match[2] AS sdk_version
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sdk FROM d) unq,
     regexp_match(unq.sdk, '([^0-9/]*)/*([0-9.]*)') re (match);
```

The regular expression does the following:

1. `([^0-9/]*)` Capture everything up to the first digit or forward slash. Note that this will also match SDK names that have characters other than `A-Za-z`.
2. `/*`         Jump over a forward slash, if present
3. `([0-9.]*)`  Capture any following digits or dots. If you are confident that only digits and dots will follow then you can also do `(*)`.

Note also that I put the `DISTINCT` clause in a separate subquery. It is not very efficient to first process every row to then throw out any duplicates. Instead, get rid of the duplicates first.

**Pre PG-10 versions**

The function `regexp_match()` was introduced in version 10. If you have an older version then you can use `regexp_matches()` without the `g` flag for the same result (PG8.3+).

Comment: The used expression in `regexp_match()` with two patterns is virtually equivalent to two simple regex matches. Additionally, the function has to create an array and the query must unnest it. This cannot be faster than two `substring()` calls. [See my benchmarks.](https://paste.depesz.com/s/jJF)

Comment: @klin Your solution does not include the `DISTINCT` clause that the OP is asking for. That makes the benchmarks rather incomparable. Results will depend significantly on the proportion of duplicates, which in the case of your benchmarking data set is less than 2% (1,277 out of 87,684). I can imagine that in this scenario (table of apps developed with a certain SDK?) the proportion of duplicates is much higher.

Comment: You're right, I should've removed `DISTINCT` from your query or add it to other ones. Still it is remarkably slower than mine.

Comment: Assuming all I really need is the regexp_match as a column. If so, this might work for me. I am going to try it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at this again, I really don't understand what is going on with `regexp_match(unq.sdk, '([^0-9/]*)/*([0-9.]*)') re (match)`. What is `re(match)` actually doing? where `re` reference?

Comment: @CraigConover `regexp_match()` is a set-returning function; `re` is an alias for the result, otherwise the system generates a name and then you can't easily refer to it. Similarly with `(match)`, that is a list (of 1 item) of column name aliases.